# MySQL jdbc -Servlet connection in eclipse with null pointer exception

Tags: mysql, eclipse, servlets

It is a simple program where Registration servlet should validate data submitted via the HTML forms and store it in a database table using JDBC
the error i get is 
HTTP Status 500 -

---

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException

the connection object returns null

```
public ConnectionClass() {
try {
     //Step 2: Load MySQL Java driver
       Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception at loading Driver class");
    }
}

private Connection createConnection() {
Connection connection = null;
try {
        //Step 3: Establish Java MySQL connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("CONNECTION ERROR");
    }
    return connection;
}
```

1) checked the url user and password 
2) configured the datasource and successfully pinged
3) checked for mysqlconnector jar files

anything else to look out for? please do let me know as I'm new to servlets concepts

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a bug in the createConnection method, no matter if the connection fails you return the object, if the connection fails it returns null. And you are not writing the exception.

You can change the method in this way:

```
private Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
     Connection connection = null;
     try {
        //Step 3: Establish Java MySQL connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("CONNECTION ERROR");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throws e;
     }        
}
```

Now you don't get a null, if something goes wrong it throw the real exception and